# While is not working with 'and' and 'or'

Tags: python, while-loop

```
while (bulbasaur[0] > 0) or (charmander[0] > 0):
#I get an EOF error here

while (bulbasaur[0] > 0) or (charmander[0] > 0)
#and a syntax error here
```

Does anyone know how to make while work with `or`?

Comment: You're missing a `:` in the second while statement at least. Have you added a body of code correctly indented for the first `while` statement ?

Comment: `EOFError` isn't coming from your `while` condition.  Show the body of your loop.

Comment: @FatalError Take a look at Collin's answer

Comment: @pydsigner: Yeah, seems plausible after all.

Answer (score 10):

In the first example, you're missing the loop body. There has to be something there, if you need an empty loop, you can use `pass`:

```
while (bulbasaur[0] > 0) or (charmander[0] > 0):
    pass
```

In the second example, you're just missing the `:` to start the new block.

For reference:

When running the following blurb in Python 3.3, I get "Unexpected EOF while parsing"

```
x = 'a'
while (x == 'a') or (x == 'b'):
```

When running it in Python 2.7, I get "Expected an indented block".

Comment: He's getting an EOF...

Comment: @pydsigner My python 2.7 gives "expected an indented block", but my python 3 gives "unexpected EOF while parsing"

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense then. I was thinking "file read" or something.